# Set size of ImageView in px at runtime

Tags: android, image

I want to put 8 image thumbs in one horizontal line, using the whole available width.
The images are retrieved from a webservice which lets me specify the dimensions.
I tried the following:

```
int widthPx = container.getWidth();
LinearLayout thumbs = (LinearLayout)curView.findViewById(R.id.thumbs);
    for(int i=0; i<pics.length; i++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContextt);

        int thumbSize = widthPx / 8;

        try {
            String url = "http://someurl/" + pics[i] + "&width=" + thumbSize  + "&height=" + thumbSize;
            URL imgUrl = new URL(url);
            Drawable imgD = Drawable.createFromStream(imgUrl.openStream(), "src");
            iv.setImageDrawable(imgD);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "loading image failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        thumbs.addView(iv);
    }
```

The LinearLayout thumbs has android:layout_width="fill_parent set. The thumbs produced by this code are significantly smaller then 1/8 of the width. Why is this? What would be the correct way?

Update:
This code is inside *onCreateView* of a Fragment. While my width value is calculated based on the root-view and is correct, *thumbs.getWidth()* returns 0, although the view is inflated before and should also have a width of 480 because of layout_width is set to fill_parent. I'm not sure if that's a problem.

Is my assumption correct that the layout of the created ImageViews is set to wrap_content by default? If not, how to set this with Java code?

Comment: What is container? What is the number you get with `container.getWidth();`?

Comment: container here is a FrameLayout which acts as root for a Fragment where this code is from. getWidth() on it correctly returns 480, the single thumbs thus are 60x60px. Is this somehow related to px / dip transformation?

Comment: If you use `thumbs.addView (iv, new LayoutParams(thumbSize, thumbSize);` does it make it the right size?

Comment: Yes, it does. So I guess wrap_content is not the default layout. What's the default layout? How to change to wrap_content in Java?

Comment: I answered the last part in your new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `ImageView`s with a fixed size, i.e.:

```
thumbs.addView (iv, new LayoutParams(thumbSize, thumbSize));
```

---

To answer (partially) the questions in the comments:

The [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) API says:

> takes care of computing its measurement from the image so that it can be used in any layout manager

so it is probably assuming 60px for a 160 dpi (I may be wrong there).

Comment: That's interesting. My device has 240 dpi. Does that mean it scales the 60px down? If so, can I somehow prevent it from doing so for images loaded dynamically? I guess for local images it doesn't happen if they are available in drawable-hdpi folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Play with the values returned by [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html). You can get the density from your display with it. Regarding to the second, that's why you separate the in different folders, right?

Comment: Does that mean that Android always treats remote images as if they were loaded from drawable (160dpi) folder? Is the recommended way to prevent scaling in this cases to manually set LayoutParameters as suggested here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using this:

```
widthPx = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```