# ImageView is being re-sized - why?

Tags: android

I have the following image in my app: It's a 59x60 PNG.

[image]

I use it in the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/headerContainer"       
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_bt_refresh"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run it in my Nexus One, the width of the ImageView is 89 pixels. Why?

Comment: It might be the case that your image is being resized based on the dpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here: [Set size of ImageView in px at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169927/set-size-of-imageview-in-px-at-runtime/6170139#6170139)

It is resizing it due to a different screen density than the base 160 dpi:

59x240/160 = 88.5

A workaround is to use `android:layout_width="59px"` and `android:layout_height="60"`

Comment: True, but the DPI of my image is 72... So I wondered why it got larger on a 240dpi screen...

Comment: The calculation is to maintain the same size as it would have in a 160 dpi screen.