# How can i use particular size of image to all screen resolution in android gaming?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do i set images for all screen resolution by coding in custom view? not by creating xml

Comment: am drawing a long strip with a single image how do i fix it for all type of screen resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a `LinearLayout` with `fill_parent` parameters and fit the image in there, you could accomplish this.  Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169927/set-size-of-imageview-in-px-at-runtime) for code examples.

As far as "all screen resolutions" goes, Android mostly takes care of that.  If you want an image to fill a portion of the width of your screen (perhaps what you mean by "strip"?), then use `fill_parent` width and `wrap_content` height attributes.  Or, if you want the image to fill only half the width of that "strip", get the device's width in pixels and divide by 2, i.e.
`getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); / 2`, and set the `ImageView`'s dimensions that way.  This will accommodate any Android device since you're setting different values for the image depending on the device, not hard-coding an arbitrary value for the dimensions, e.g. 100px.

Does this cover what you're trying to ask?  Your question isn't too specific.

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);